# JS: Insert a value into input type date

Tags: javascript

I want to insert a current date into an input in form with javascript, but it is not working, here are my codes:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("registrationday").value = getDay()

  function getDay() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    today =  "\"" + yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + "\"";
    return today
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="date" id="registrationday" name="registrationday" disabled>
```

Comment: There is NO need to use a custom function for what you are trying to achieve. just use this `document.getElementById('registrationday').valueAsDate = new Date();`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("registrationday").value = getDay()

  function getDay() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    today =  yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    return today
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="date" id="registrationday" name="registrationday" disabled>
```

However, a better solution is just to assign the current date to the input's `valueAsDate` property (suggested by [@Always Helping](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13669048/always-helping)):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("registrationday").valueAsDate = getDay()

  function getDay() {
    return new Date()
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="date" id="registrationday" name="registrationday" disabled>
```

Comment: why NOT -> `document.getElementById('registrationday').valueAsDate = new Date();`  - keep it simple ayyy.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Yes, that's certainly a better solution. I was simply pointing out what was wrong with OP's solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
var currentDate= new Date();

var day = ("0" + currentDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

var today = currentDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;

document.getElementById("datepicker").value = today;
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved with this JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
var date = new Date ();
var day = datum.getDate(),
    month = datum.getMonth() + 1,
    year = datum.getFullYear();
var today = day + "-" + month + "-" + day ;

document.getElementById('registrationday').value = today;  
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="date" id="registrationday" name="registrationday" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns `"\"2021-10-17\""` which is invalid format (unnecessary slash, and double quote)

Just change `"\"" + yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + "\"";`

To: `today =  yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;` at it will return correct output `2021-10-17`